# How to pass a value from child to parent component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

I had a child component `UploadImage.js` and parent component `Parent.js`. I am uploading an image and want to pass the value of file name to the `Parent.js` component. How can I do so?

**UploadImage.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';

.
.
.

const UploadImage = () => {

    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
    const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
        accept: {
            'image/*': []
        },
        onDrop: acceptedFiles => {
            setFiles(acceptedFiles.map(file => Object.assign(file, {
                preview: URL.createObjectURL(file)
            })));
        }
    });

    //preview component
    const thumbs = files.map(file => (
        <div style={thumb} className="d-flex flex-row mt-1 col-12 mx-auto" key={file.name}>
            <div style={thumbInner}>
                <img
                    src={file.preview}
                    style={img}
                    // Revoke data uri after image is loaded
                    onLoad={() => { URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview) }}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        
    )
    );

    //wanted to pass file[0].name to Parent Component
    console.log(files.length > 0 ? files[0].name : "")


    useEffect(() => {
        // Make sure to revoke the data uris to avoid memory leaks, will run on unmount
        return () => files.forEach(file => URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview));
    }, []);

    return (
        <section className="container">
            <div {...getRootProps({ className: 'dropzone mx-3 text-center mt-4 mb-2 p-3 bg-light border border-primary border-1 rounded-4 ' })}>
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                <p className='fw-bold text-primary'>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
            </div>
            <aside style={thumbsContainer} className="d-flex flex-row">
                {thumbs}
                
            </aside>
        </section>
    );
}

export default UploadImage;
```

And my Parent component is like this

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import UploadImage from "../components/uploadImage";

const Parent = () => {
  const [uploadFileName, setUploadFileName] = useState("");

  
  return (
    <div className="mx-3 mt-4 mb-2">
      <UploadImage />

      <h3 className="m-3">{uploadFileName} </h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadButton;
```

How can I display the file name from `UploadImage.js` to `Parent.js` in the uploadFileName state ???

Comment: You can use `CallBack Functions` to do the same.

Comment: define a state in parent , pass the function to set state in child component , set the state in child component and access the same in parent . In addition to that , i think you can also use , useRef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create a function in your parent element like:

```
const NameSetter = imageName => {
  setUploadFileName(imageName);
}
```

and then send the NameSetter as a prop to your child element like:

```
<UploadImage nameHandler={NameSetter} />
```

and then in your child element you call the nameHandler prop like:

(call this when you get the name, for ex: on the callback of your backend )

```
props.nameHandler('name of your image');
```

Comment: Where I had to define props here , like this `const UploadImage = (props) => {.....}` ?

Comment: Yeah mentioned the props and now its working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use call back props to update the children to parent.

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import UploadImage from "../components/uploadImage";

const Parent = () => {
  const [uploadFileName, setUploadFileName] = useState("");

  
  return (
    <div className="mx-3 mt-4 mb-2">
      <UploadImage setUploadFileName={setUploadFileName}/>

      <h3 className="m-3">{uploadFileName} </h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadButton;
```

Then you can set whereever you want to call in child it will update in parent component. You can check through by adding consoling on the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

You should move `const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);` to `Parents.js` and then pass them by `Props` for `UploadImage.js`.

```
// UploadImage Component
    const UploadImage = (props) => {
        const {files, onUpdateFiles} = props;
        const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
            accept: {
                'image/*': []
            },
            onDrop: acceptedFiles => {
              onUpdateFiles(acceptedFiles.map(file => Object.assign(file, {
                    preview: URL.createObjectURL(file)
                })));
            }
        });
    ...
    }
```

---

```
// Parents component
    const Parent = () => {
      const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
      return (
        <div className="mx-3 mt-4 mb-2">
          <UploadImage files={files} onUpdateFiles={setFiles}  />
          {files.length > 0 && <h3 className="m-3">{files[0].name}</h3>}
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey MagnusEffect you're almost correct, just make these changes-
In UploadImage.js-

```
const UploadImage = ({setUploadFileName}) => {
<input {...getInputProps()} onChange=
{(e)=>setUploadFileName(e.target.files[0].name)} />
}
```

While in Parent Component just pass setvalues-

```
const Parent = () => {
const [uploadFileName, setUploadFileName] = useState("");
return (
<div className="mx-3 mt-4 mb-2">
<UploadImage setUploadFileName={setUploadFileName} />
<h3 className="m-3">{uploadFileName} </h3>
</div>
);
}
```

Hope this code will help to solve your query if you still facing issue, just lemme know i will help you more. Thanks

Comment: I tried your solution but its not setting the the value to the state `uploadFileName`